# Reading from database and writing to local drive, big data

Tags: netezza, bigdata, database

I would like to get a data from netezza databse which is of 5 gb and write it to a local drive. I tried the following:

```
pd.concat([chunk for chunk in (pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM table""",conn,chunksize=10000))]).to_sql('table1',conn1)
```

This takes plenty of time, almost a day. Could any one please suggest an alternative to do the process quickly, so I can deal with a bigger data of 25 gb?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only requirement to store data at drive from DB then you can uSe following options-

```
nzsql -u user -pw pwd -db database -o abc.dat -c "sql"
```

Or

nzsql -u user -pw pwd -db database -c "sql" > abc.dat

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [transient external table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_transient_external_tables.html).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'c:\localFileName.dat' USING (RemoteSource 'ODBC' delim '|')
as SELECT * FROM table;
```